# Drupal 7 examples module not working

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I just installed Drupal 7 examples module but when i try to access any of the menu like `examples/ajax_example/simplest` it takes to 403 service not available page.
I just enabled 'AJAX examples' and 'Examples For Developers' module only.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Make sure you have kept the examples module in /sites/all folder.
Step 2: Go to this url hostname_or_address/admin/build/modules.
Step 3: Enable all the modules related to examples.
Step 4: Make sure navigation is coming in left or right side bar.
Step 5: Clear cache and go to home page.

Done !!

You can refer to the below site how it looks.
http://d7.drupalexamples.info/examples/ajax_example/simplest